# Impact of "cleartext HTTP URL schemes for Proxy Automatic Configuration (PAC) is now deprecated" on IOS 15 beta app

Tags: ios, pac

As in September new version ios i.e. IOS 15 is coming. There are some APIs getting depricated. I have a concern about "cleartext HTTP URL schemes for Proxy Automatic Configuration (PAC) is now deprecated".

Support for cleartext HTTP URL schemes for Proxy Automatic Configuration (PAC) is now deprecated. Use only HTTPS URL schemes for PAC. This affects all PAC configurations including, but not limited to, configurations set via Settings, System Preferences, profiles, and URLSession APIs such as connectionProxyDictionary, and CFNetworkExecuteProxyAutoConfigurationURL(*:*:*:*:). If you configure a cleartext HTTP PAC URL, the system may upgrade it to HTTPS during PAC file loads. Web Proxy Auto-Discovery (WPAD) Protocol via DNS isn’t affected. Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) Option 252 WPAD may attempt to upgrade cleartext HTTP URLs to HTTPS during PAC file loads. (61981845)

1. What we need to change in the iOS app or react native app?
2. What will exactly not support in the IOS app or react native app?
3. What is the relation between PAC and IOS app?
4. What will not going to work?